# Feature test for float/double variants of std::from_chars?

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion

I'd like to write a C++17 shim that substitutes custom implementation of [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) in case the float/double variants are not available (e.g. GCC < 11 has only integers). However, the feature test macro [`__cpp_lib_to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/feature_test) only differentiates general support of `from_chars` and is satisfied even when only the integer variant is implemented. How should I figure out whether the float/double variants are supported? Do I need to do it via compiled feature tests?

Comment: Are you using some kind of build-system like [the venerable autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), [CMake](https://cmake.org), or [Meson](https://mesonbuild.com)? Then you can create a check that attempt to build a small example program which uses the feature you're looking for, and if it doesn't exist then the build will fail and you can detect it and add your replacements.

Comment: Yes, of course I could write a compile test. But I thought feature test macros were introduced into C++ exactly to allow getting rid of these tests...

Comment: Since the specification added both integer and floating point variants simultaneously in the C++17 specification, I guess the authors didn't think there would be a need to separate feature test macros. If e.g. floating point support was optional, or was added in C++20 instead, then such a feature test macro would make sense.